# Chrome HAR File size limitation

Tags: google-chrome, har

### Environment

- Windows 10
- Chrome Version 66.0.3359.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)

### Problem at hand

For debugging purpose, I log network traffic and save it as a HAR file.
When the resulting HAR file is large ( > ~12Mb ) it's content is truncated, resulting an Invalid JSON object.

- **Might I be doing something wrong?**
- **Is this a known issue?**
- **Anyone has encountered something similar in the past ?**

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the solution for everyone, but I've just checked that Opera v56 allows HAR file that contains a JSON object that is 1.1MB.

Chrome and Firefox both truncated the same JSON data object.

However that overall HAR output file from Opera somehow also accumulated to a very large size of 221MB.

Answer (score 1):

Just strange behavior on my Chrome 80 on Ubuntu: HAR file wrote fast first 8MB (in this case file truncated), after that file continue writing very slow (~1MB in minute) and go to 75MB (in my case) in hour or more.

Answer (score 0):

*** Disclaimer: This answer is from the developers of HttpWatch ***

I'm not sure why you are seeing HAR file truncation but you could try using HttpWatch:

https://www.httpwatch.com

It does not have a limit on the size of the output HAR file and can also record in a more compact HWL file format.